# How much memory is available for database use in memsql

Tags: memory-management, singlestore

I have created memsql cluster on 7 machines. One of the machine shows that out of 62.86 GB only 2.83 is used. So here I am assuming that around 60 GB
memory is available to store data.
[image]

But my top command tell another story

[image]

Here we can see that about 21.84 GB memory is getting used and free memory is 41 GB. 
So

**1> How much exact memory is available for database? Is it 60 Gb as per cluster URL or 42 Gb as per top command**

Note that:

1>memsql-op is consuming aroung 13.5 g virtual memory.

2> as per 'top' if we subtract buffered and cached memory's total size from used memory, then it comes to 2.83GB which is used memory as per cluster URL

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you currently have about 60GB of memory free to be used by any process on your machine including the MemSQL database.  Note that MemSQL has some overhead and by default reserves a small percentage of the total memory for overhead.  If you visit the status page in the MemSQL Ops UI and view the "Leaf Table Memory" card, you will discover the amount of memory that can be used for data storage within the leaf nodes of your MemSQL cluster.

MemSQL Ops is written in Python which is then embedded into a "single binary" via a packaging tool.  Because of this it exhibits a couple of oddities including high VM use.  Note that this should not affect the amount of data you can store, as Ops is only consuming 308MB of resident memory on your machine.  It should stay relatively constant based on the size of your cluster.